# Apex Controller method not firing

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to teach myself apex and visualforce, but I ran into a little snag. I have an Apex controller method called exerciseSelected that should be fired upon the press of an apex:commandButton, however it is not firing. Here is the visualforce page and controller:

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MaxDashboardComponentController" >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Exercise: "/>
                <apex:selectList value="{!exerciseName}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions id="SelectedOption" value="{!Options}"></apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!exerciseSelected}" value="Go" />
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```java
public class MaxDashboardComponentController {
    public List<Exercise__c> exercises {get; set;}
    public String exerciseName {get; set;}
    public List<selectOption> options {get{
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<Exercise__c> unfilteredExercises = new List<Exercise__c>(exercises);
        List<Exercise__c> filteredExercises = filterDups(unfilteredExercises);
        for(Exercise__c e : filteredExercises){
            options.add(new SelectOption(e.Name, e.Name));
        } 
        return options;
    } set;}

    public MaxDashboardComponentController(){
        exercises = new List<Exercise__c>();
        // get our data & wrap 
        for (Exercise__c e : [Select id, Name, one_rep_max__c, date_completed__c FROM Exercise__c LIMIT 2000]) {
            exercises.add(e);
        }
        this.exercises = exercises;
    }

    public pageReference exerciseSelected(){
        system.debug('test');
        return null;
    }

    //filter out duplicates by name
    public List<exercise__c> filterDups(List<Exercise__c> unfilteredList){
        Map<String, boolean> exerciseMap = new Map<String, boolean>();
        List<Exercise__c> returnList = new List<Exercise__c>();
        for(Exercise__c e : unfilteredList){
            if(!exerciseMap.containsKey(e.Name)){
                exerciseMap.put(e.name, true);
                returnList.add(e);
            }
        }       

        return returnList;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getOptions(){
        return options;
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Do not see any reason why `exerciseSelected` would not be fired, when you click on that button, expected behavior is to see `test` in logs

Comment: Correct, however the logs are blank

Comment: Also, if I comment out the selectOptions tag in my markup, the method will fire as expected, though my list is now empty.

Comment: Can u add reRender attribute in command button and refresh form only

Comment: Same result. it reRenders based on ID right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting an exception that you are masking due to absence of `apex:pageMessages`.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!exerciseNames}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions id="SelectedOption" value="{!Options}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
```

`<apex:SelectList value="..">`  needs to be bound to a singleton property, not a `List<String> exerciseNames` unless you use the optional attribute `multiselect="true"`.

Note that `apexSelectOptions` should be bound to a list of SelectOption (as you  have) but the id you chose implies a singleton (`id="selectedOption"` - more properly the id of the `selectList`)

Comment: Very good observation! :)

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. I changed exerciseNames to exerciseName and made it a string instead of a list of strings. That seemed to have fixed my issue. 

So the value attribute of selectList is the actual selected value(s). I guess I didn't really understand a explanation on the salesforce page at first. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.   I found it counterintuitive at first too back when I was learning VF